# Changing theme of Android Application via CheckBox onClick

Tags: java, android, checkbox, styles

I am a new android developer and I am working on a project where I want to have custom color themes as an option in the settings in one of my apps. I have four check boxes, call them checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4. I also have four custom styles in my styles.xml file, call them theme1, theme2, theme3, theme4. Here is my .java file coding regarding handling the onClick of these CheckBoxes:

```
checkBoxListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(blueCheckBox.isChecked()){
                //Change theme to blue
            }
            if(redCheckBox.isChecked()){
                //Change theme to red
            }
            if(greenCheckBox.isChecked()){
                //Change theme to green
            }
            if(bwCheckBox.isChecked()){
                 //Change theme to Black & White
            }
        }
    };
    blueCheckBox.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    redCheckBox.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    greenCheckBox.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    bwCheckBox.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
}
```

How can I set the style of my entire application to the corresponding custom declared styles I have in the body's of these if statements? Thank you for your time, I appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2):

for this you have to create some themes under `/style/`

For Example :

```
<resources>
    <style name="LightTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="BlackTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    </style>    
</resources>
```

and at java side you can use it like...

```
if (lightThemeCheckBox.isChecked()) {
    getApplication().setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
} else {
    getApplication().setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);
}
```

i hope this will help you.

for more visit this link:
http://www.anddev.org/applying_a_theme_to_your_application-t817.html

Comment: Thank you so much the java portion of the code you gave me was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: So This is what I have at this point after playing around with the code and even using getApplication().setTheme(R.style.myTheme) it still will not change the background of my application, and I think it has to do with my themes. I simply have this as my theme code for example:

<item name="android:background">#66cccc</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#17577e</item>

this is the body of a custom style I don't think its doing what I want. I want the text of all my buttons and textviews to change color, as well as the background of the app, but no the background of the buttons

Comment: Here it is 2 links which will help you to build custom themes,
1> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
2> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_theme_demo_example.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hi You are able to supply the button for Checkbox by set the Background for the CheckBox as Follows :

Below the Code is for backgound xml file for Checkbox: Name as checkbox_selection.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_active_320" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_inactive_320" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_inactive_320" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_active_320" android:state_checked="true"/>
```

Here You found that there was having the drawable resource such as check_active_320 when User checked on CheckBox and check_inactive_320 for Checkbox which is not checked.

the code to set the above xml to CheckBox as Follows:

```
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/radioread"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textread"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textread"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selection"
        android:focusable="false" />
```

Here You can find the android:button as the value of our style.